# ShowHTMLDialog and buttons style

Tags: windows, winapi, mshtml

I use the win32 ShowHTMLDialog function to display in my application an HTML popup that contains some standard HTML buttons. But for some reasons, these buttons are not rendered the same way they are in IE: they are not rounded and there is no 3D effect.

Is there a way to change this programmatically and get something similar to the IE rendering? (which is kind of strange as I thought Trident was used in both cases ...)

Thanks.

Comment: which version of IE are you comparing this to?

Comment: i cant post a reply to this question!?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the new look buttons your application needs to be linked to the version 6 common controls.

[Enabling Visual Styles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms649781(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN has some information on how to do this. The quickest way is to add the following directive to one of your projects c++ or header files :-

```
#pragma comment(linker,"/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' "\ 
  "version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
```